# ZSH Theme only partially applied

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

[image: shell]

having this weird behavior where only the date themeing on the right is being applied by my chosen jonathan theme for zsh. just downloaded and set it up using debains suggested rc file. Im assuming there is something in here overwriting the theme but i have no idea what.
zshrc

```
# Set path if required
#export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH

# Aliases
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -lah --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias ec="$EDITOR $HOME/.zshrc" # edit .zshrc
alias sc="source $HOME/.zshrc"  # reload zsh configuration

# Set up the prompt - if you load Theme with zplugin as in this example, this will be overriden by the Theme. If you comment out the Theme in zplugins, this will be loaded.
autoload -Uz promptinit
promptinit
prompt adam1            # see Zsh Prompt Theme below

# Use vi keybindings even if our EDITOR is set to vi
bindkey -e

setopt histignorealldups sharehistory

# Keep 5000 lines of history within the shell and save it to ~/.zsh_history:
HISTSIZE=5000
SAVEHIST=5000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history

# Use modern completion system
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

# zplug - manage plugins
source /usr/share/zplug/init.zsh
zplug "plugins/git", from:oh-my-zsh
zplug "plugins/sudo", from:oh-my-zsh
zplug "plugins/command-not-found", from:oh-my-zsh
zplug "zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting"
zplug "zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions"
zplug "zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search"
zplug "zsh-users/zsh-completions"
zplug "junegunn/fzf"
zplug "themes/jonathan", from:oh-my-zsh, as:theme   # Theme
# ZSH_THEME=
# zplug - install/load new plugins when zsh is started or reloaded
if ! zplug check --verbose; then
    printf "Install? [y/N]: "
    if read -q; then
        echo; zplug install
    fi
fi
zplug load --verbose
```

it should look like this,
[image: jonathan]

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by commenting out this line

```
prompt adam1            # see Zsh Prompt Theme below
```